# How to do table aliases using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I need to do something like this. Where you can put a alias in front of the column name. o. c. etc

`SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName FROM...`

**Here is the entire query im trying to replicate in sequelize**

`SELECT c.id AS comment_id, c.comment, r.id AS reply_id, r.parent_comment_id, r.comment AS reply_comment FROM (comments c) LEFT JOIN comments r ON c.id = r.parent_comment_id`

**What I tried**

```
attributes: ['c.id', ['comment_id'], 'c.comment', 'r.id', ['reply_id'], 'r.parent_comment_id', 'r.comment', ['reply_comment']]
```

**Documentation from sequelize only shows how to do one attribute**

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['foo', ['baz']]
});
```

SELECT foo AS baz ...

Comment: can you explain in detail what actually you want?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp The part where it says  Alias for Tables Example. I want to be able to put a alias in front of the column.

Comment: Have you tried " attributes:[ ['field1, 'alias1'] , ['field2', 'alias2'] ] " ?

Answer (score 19):

Each field you want an alias to, you need to pass as a two position array.

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'foo', // do not use alias
    ['bar', 'baz'],       // uses alias 'baz' for column 'bar'
    [Sequelize.col('related.foo'), 'related_foo']  // alias on includes
  ],
  includes: [
    {
      model: related,
      attributes: [] // empty to not generate nested atributes.
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

when you create alias for table  you can access the corresponding column's within the table

`e:g`  `SELECT o.cols1, o.cols2 FROM table o`

Comment: I need to know how to do it in sequelize.

Comment: I dont know if this is right. the documentation only shows how to do one attribute. But I need to do many. This is what I did.                                                                

  attributes: ['c.id', ['comment_id'], c.comment, r.id, ['reply_id'], r.parent_comment_id, r.comment, ['reply_comment']]

Answer (score 0):

You can give an alias to any table as follows:

```
comments.belongsTo(comments, , { as: 'r', foreignKey: 'id' })
comments.hasMany(comments, { foreignKey: 'parent_comment_id' )
```

Note you must strictly specify the field name for the relationship in order for this to work.

You can find it [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) inside **Naming strategy**

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is using self join in Sequelize i.e according to your query in question. link - > [sequelize self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455380/how-to-self-join-using-sequelize-in-node)
  after creating the self join relationship model, you need to include the same model again. and an attribute section, you have to create alias related to that model. here is the example below... I am assuming the comment is your model.. because you have not provided any code of your model...

```
Model.comment.findAll({
  attributes: [

    ['id', 'comment_id'],   // uses alias 'comment_id' for column 'c.id'
    comment                 // c.comment no alias
  ],
  includes: [
    {
      model: comment,
      attributes: [
    ["id"," reply_id"],      // r.id as reply_id
    parent_comment_id ,        //r.parent_comment_id no alias
     ["comment","reply_comment "] //r.comment as reply_comment
                 ] 
    }
  ]
});
```